# Passing HTML form data in the URL on local machine (file://)

Tags: html, forms

I'm building a small HTML/JS application for primary use on local machine (i.e. everything is accessed via `file://` protocol, though maybe in the future it will be hosted on a server within intranet).

I'm trying to make a form with `method="get"` and `action="target.html"`, in the hope that the browser will put form data in the URL (like, `file://<path>/target.html?param1=aaa&param2=bbb`). However, it's not happening (target.html opens fine, but no parameters is passed).

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to use forms over `file://` at all? I can always build the url manually (via JS), but being lazy I'd prefer the browser do it for me. ;)

Here is my sample form:

```
<form name='config' action="test_form.html" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="param1">
    <input type="text" name="param2">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be some browser specific restriction. What browser are you using?

I tested this in Firefox 3.6.3 and Internet Explorer 8, and it works just fine.

Comment: That's weird.. I just made a bare-bones test and it works indeed! Investigating the differences...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was stupid. The controls of my form are generated dynamically (via JS), and the generation function was setting `id`s for them, but not `name`s. So, from the `form`'s point of view, there was no parameters at all.

Thanks to Guffa for providing me a nudge in the right direction!